# Way to see deployment status of kubernetes pods in grafana

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus, istio

Is there a way to see the status of pod deployments (success / failure) in grafana or is this only possible on the kubernetes dashboard? 
I ask because we want to expose the grafana dashboard to our micro service engineers so they can see some pod metrics and hopefully the status of theire deployments but we try to avoid exposing the kubernetes dashboard to them.

Best regards

Comment: what about using something like Kiali? https://www.kiali.io/ (in Kiali deployment status is shown as part of the health)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, please see the setup here:

[Promethous grafana Setup](https://akomljen.com/get-kubernetes-cluster-metrics-with-prometheus-in-5-minutes/)

Other ways to do these dashboards are:

- deploy metricbeat as daemonset on the cluster with kibana dashboards to ELK
- deploy fluentd as dameond set to get the same

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the link! Will look at that next week!