# prometheus grafana - see pods status

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I am trying to build a graph that shows the status of the pods in a namespace (ready/failed and so on...) over time.

I believe the kube_pod_status_phase() function might be what I need here but I can't seem to be able to show that data in a clear way in grafana. Also, I am only interested in pod name, namespace, and phase. I am not sure how I could filter out the other columns.

I would actually like to see both the history of the pod (when it failed, or was in ready state, etc...) and the current status of the pod.

thank you

Comment: `kube_pod_status_phase` is a metric, not a function. Some details are missing from your question to help you achieve what you are tying to do. How would you like your graph to look like? Should it show the number of pods in each phase across the entire cluster?

Comment: Doing some research, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52882117/16922342) that can be useful to solve your question.